# How do I make a cell return the name of a column in a data set, given certain numerical value requirements?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example,
There are 3 students, with different scores from each unit.
I want the unit with the value 5 or lower score to show in the column "Student needs to focus on" without me having to look through the table. The first value that is  5 or lower starting from the left should be the point of reference of the column name, completely disregarding other columns on the right that meet the same requirement.
If my explanation is confusing (because it is confusing to me haha), please take a look at the table which is my desired outcome. The bolded part is what I want excel to calculate and output.

[Example of desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH96W.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

> =INDEX($B$1:$D$1,,MATCH(TRUE,B2:D2<6,))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your example, say the upper left cell is A1 and the whole table is then in the range A1:E4 with the actual scores being in B2:D4.

Given that, the following formula does the job:

```
=SMALL(IFERROR((B3:I3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:I3))/((B3:I3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:I3)))*(B3:I3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:I3)),""),1)
```

Looks hideous, right? but it's really much simpler than it looks. `(B3:I3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:I3))` is the basic element. It will produce 0's for any score >5. To remove those, it is divided by itself so that it returns errors where the 0's were. For the <=5 cells though, it had returned the column they were in and we wanted those numbers. Dividing by itself changed those to 1's. So we multiply that division result by this element giving us back the column numbers for the <=5's. Those error stay errors.

Now we write an `IFERROR()` function around the whole result changing the errors to blanks. That makes the <=5 column numbers the only non-blank values left. We then write a `SMALL()` function around the `IFERROR()` and tell it to return the smallest value which, since they are column numbers, is the first <=5 score in the row.

You show the desired return being "Unit" and a number. I wrote the formula to work with exactly what you showed, so it strung together the word "Unit" and the column number.

Likely your actual situation is a little more complicated. If not, just use the above and change those cell references as needed. But if those headings are less regular, perhaps something like "English|Math|Science", then you need to take the formula and wrap one more function around it, an `INDEX()` function:

```
=INDEX(B1:D1,1,SMALL(IFERROR((B3:D3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:D3))/((B3:D3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:D3)))*(B3:D3<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B3:D3)),""),1))
```

`INDEX()` takes a range, B1:D1 in this case, and returns to you a particular row and column of it. There is only 1 row, so that's easy, and the column comes from the first formula. It returns then, the column heading for the column that contains the first <=5 score.

By the way, for the first formula, a nicer looking version of it, using the `LET()` function, looks like this:

```
=LET(Column,  (B2:D2<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B2:D2))+0,

     SMALL(IFERROR(Column/Column*Column,""),1))
```

That long, nasty-looking first formula became just `SMALL(IFERROR(Column/Column*Column,""),1)` and the last formula would then be:

```
=LET(Column,  (B2:D2<=5)*SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(B2:D2))+0,

     INDEX(B1:D1,1,SMALL(IFERROR(Column/Column*Column,""),1)))
```